How to send Bedrock's results to S3 using LangChain
boto3 Has the option to configure S3 bucket as the target of the LLM model's output(outputDataConfig):
import boto3

bedrock = boto3.client(service_name="bedrock")

inputDataConfig=({
    "s3InputDataConfig": {
        "s3Uri": "s3://input-bucket/input/abc.jsonl"
    }
})

outputDataConfig=({
    "s3OutputDataConfig": {
        "s3Uri": "s3://output-bucket/output/"
    }
})

response=bedrock.create_model_invocation_job(
    roleArn="arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyBatchInferenceRole",
    modelId="amazon.titan-text-express-v1",
    jobName="my-batch-job",
    inputDataConfig=inputDataConfig,
    outputDataConfig=outputDataConfig
)

jobArn = response.get('jobArn')

I there a similar feature in Langchain? I couldn't find it in their documentation.
